# MMC application crashes when trying to add snap-in

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, mmc

The MMC application keeps on crashing whenever I try to add a snap-in on my PC. Google didn't really help much. Is there any way I can check whats causing it to crash? The event log doesn't help either. Are there any applications that could be causing this issue? At the moment I have VS 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio installed but I doubt they will cause MMC to crash. I am using Windows 7.

EDIT:

This is whats in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: mmc.exe, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bc3f1
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdadb
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000c283b
Faulting process id: 0x12f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb639a0286b28d
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 6686591e-cf8d-11df-b81e-001e0babf7a7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, i managed to find out what the issue was. For some strange reason Windows is not happy with having both SQL Server management studio 2005 and 2008 installed when I try to add a snap-in. I uninstalled 2008 and it worked fine...weird!!!

Comment: Problem was solved for me by uninstalling SQL Server 2008 from Windows 10 (which is apparently not compatible, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562)

Comment: 2017 , I do confirm that. win 10 , sql 2008 , removed it and exception was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I also have several versions of SQL server and Management Studio on Windows 10, and haven't been able to figure out which to uninstall to follow Draco's answer, but I did stumble on a neat trick: If you run MMC and specify the snap-in as a command-line argument, it will work just fine.

Example:
`mmc %SystemRoot%\system32\compmgmt.msc`

Comment: This is without a doubt, the best answer! :) Worked great for my error getting Hyper-V Manager working!